# sql db2 select records from either table

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have an order file, with order id and ship date.  Orders can only be shipped monday - friday.  This means there are no records selected for Saturday and Sunday.

I use the same order file to get all order dates, with date in the same format (yyyymmdd).

i want to select a count of all the records from the order file based on order date... and (i believe) full outer join (or maybe right join?) the date file... because i would like to see

20120330   293

20120331   0

20120401   0

20120402   920

20120403   430

20120404   827

etc...

however, my sql statement is still not returning a zero record for the 31st and 1st.

```
with DatesTable as (
   select ohordt "Date" from kivalib.orhdrpf
   where ohordt between 20120315 and 20120406
   group by ohordt order by ohordt
)

SELECT ohscdt, count(OHTXN#) "Count"

FROM KIVALIB.ORHDRPF full outer join DatesTable dts on dts."Date" = ohordt
--/*order status = filled & order type = 1 & date between (some fill date range)*/

WHERE OHSTAT = 'F' AND OHTYP = 1 and ohscdt between 20120401 and 20120406

GROUP BY ohscdt ORDER BY ohscdt
```

any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Instead of building `DatesTable` on the fly, I recommend building a calendar file, which has every date (in some range) in it.  Also, it's best to use the built-in date/time/timestamp datatypes, not some formatted number/string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there is no data for those days, they do not show up as rows.  You can use a recursive CTE to build a contiguous list of dates between two values that the query can join on:

It will look something like:

```
WITH dates (val) AS (
    SELECT CAST('2012-04-01' AS DATE)
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
        UNION ALL
    SELECT Val + 1 DAYS
    FROM dates
    WHERE Val < CAST('2012-04-06' AS DATE)
)

SELECT d.val AS "Date", o.ohscdt, COALESCE(COUNT(o.ohtxn#), 0) AS "Count"
FROM dates AS d
LEFT JOIN KIVALIB.ORDHRPF AS o
  ON o.ohordt = TO_CHAR(d.val, 'YYYYMMDD')
WHERE o.ohstat = 'F'
  AND o.ohtyp = 1
```